# Execute function after layout re-render in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I would like to create a popup menu when i click on a table row in svelte. I used the `document.querySelectorAll` method to add an onclick-event to every table row inside `onMount`. In the `onMount` function, I also re-render the shown table. How could I apply the onclick value to the re-rendered elements?

```
onMount(() => {
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".results .table table tbody tr"));
  /* -> returns array with only 1 element -> not correct */

  /* ... re-render logic here */
}
```

but when I add an timeout:

```
onMount(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".results .table table tbody tr"));
  }, 5000);
  /* -> returns array with all elements */

  /* ... re-render logic here again */
}
```

A REPL with the full source-code can be found [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/a0c42405a6434e7990c2cb724ca7e1bc?version=3.12.1)

Comment: You do not need to add an on click event for every row. Catch the clicks on the table and use the target to identify the row.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer! It is true that i could use a on click event for the table and select the target, but then I would have other problems. I would get the td as the target and not the row. I would also have to detect if I clicked on the table-header or on a row. I have to get the row for the event processing

Comment: I understand you do not need th and tr clicks. So ignore them.

Comment: Can you repro the issue you're seeing in the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl)? It's very unclear what's going on. Generally speaking you shouldn't be using `document.querySelectorAll` in the context of a Svelte application — you're mixing and matching paradigms (imperative vs declarative), and that generally doesn't end well!

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I just added the REPL-link to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was writing some thoughts, but it got too long for a comment.

You're doing a decent amount of extra work in that REPL that Svelte can do for you. I agree with @voscausa that you should be delegating events to the `table`. You should almost never have to use `document.querySelector` in Svelte. You're looping through all your rows twice. All your event listener attachings should be attributes in the markup, not attached in the JS, nor attached in an initializer function (thus the event delegation to the table). You are constantly monitoring mouse position, but you only use it in the `onclick`, which is a `MouseEvent` and has access to X and Y data.

Switch the click listener to the container:

```js
<div class="results" on:click={handleClick}> ... </div>

<script>
  function handleClick(e) {
    const tr = e.target.closest('tr');
    const td = e.target.closest('td');
    if (td) {
      /* code */
    } else {
      /* code */
    }
  }
  </script>
```

If you need it to be on the whole document you can use `<svelte:window>` instead of `.results`.

To update the css of the `.option` div, do something like the following:

```js
<div class="options" style=`left:${optionsStyle.left}px;top:${optionsStyle.top}px`> ... </div>
<script>
  let optionsStyle = {left: 0, top: 0};

  function handleClick(e) {
    /* code */

    let left = 0, right = 0;
    /* calculate left and right here */
    optionsStyle  = {left: e.clientX, top: e.clientY};

    /* code */
  }
</script>
```

For toggling classes, see the [class directive](https://svelte.dev/examples#classes). You can have multiple class directives on one element. (I haven't done all of the logic here, obviously.)

```js
<div class="options" class:expand={optionsExpand}> ... </div>
<script>
  let optionsExpand = false;

  function handleClick(e) {
    const tr = e.target.closest('tr');
    const td = e.target.closest('td');
    if (td) {
      /* code */
      optionsExpand = true;
    } else {
      /* code */
      optionsExpand = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

I personally would turn the Options popup into its own component and pass the `optionsExpand` boolean as a prop.

Doing things more like I've described here will get you thinking in a Svelte mindset, it will simplify your code, you won't need the timeouts, and you won't need the `afterUpdates` function.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful post! I will rewrite the code like you have shown.

Comment: I too am in a similar boat and like this solution but not sure how I could use it in my case. I'm using a svelte-wrapped component around a non-svelte library. I need to capture mouseover events inside the component (to position my tooltip) without ability to access individual child elements of that component through svelte. While the click event only needs to grab the element under it at the time of the click, the mouseover event will needs to fire every time the target changes, and that won't happen if the event is only attached to the parent.